# Salvar caractere por caractere dentro de uma array

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 (meu retorno) 
Eu gostaria de converter uma string em um array de caracteres, um caracter em cada índice.

Gostaria que 'oi' se converte-se em  var[0] = 'o', var[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTm43.png) = 'i';

Estou fazendo uma calculadora de matriz e preciso ler os dados da matriz de uma arquivo txt, o arquivo:

2 2 
34 78 
89 -12
@
2 2
67 76
123 5

Estou lendo o arquivo com (trecho do código):

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
 FileReader(CaminhoArquivo));
```

Preciso passar cada desses caracteres(numeros) para cada indice exemplo:
[2] [2] [34] [78] [89] [@]

```
  package calculadoramatrizes;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class Conteudo {   
     public List<String> Matriz(){

     String CaminhoArquivo=("C:\\Users\\jessica borges"
            + "\\Downloads\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
            + "\\CalculadoraMatrizes-20190315T112959Z-001"
            +"\\CalculadoraMatrizes\\src\\ArquivosMatriz\\matrix.txt");

    List<String> conteudo = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CaminhoArquivo));
            String linha;
            while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                conteudo.add(linha);
            }   
             in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    System.out.println(conteudo);
    return conteudo;        

}         

public void CriaMatriz(){


}
```

}

```
    =================== main ====================

   package calculadoramatrizes;
   public class Matrix {
         public static void main(String[] args){
             chamarMatriz();
          }
          public static void chamarMatriz(){
             Conteudo ct = new Conteudo();
             ct.Matriz();
          }
    }
```

Comment: Jessica, dê uma olhada nesta dica, sobre a marcar perguntas com ' resolvido' [“Resolvido” em título de pergunta não fica parecendo coisa de fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5389/resolvido-em-t%C3%ADtulo-de-pergunta-n%C3%A3o-fica-parecendo-coisa-de-f%C3%B3rum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No trecho onde você adiciona a linha:

```
conteudo.add(linha);
```

Substitua por:

```
conteudo.addAll(Arrays.asList(linha.split(" ")));
```

`String.split(String s)` divide a a `String` em uma `String[]` onde `s` é o caractere de separação. 
`Arrays.asList(Array a)` converte a `String[]` em uma lista.
`List.addAll(Collection c)` adiciona uma coleção ao final da lista.

Seu código vai ficar aproximadamente assim:

```
try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CaminhoArquivo));
            String linha;
            while ((linha = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                // Subistitua conteudo.add(linha) por:
                conteudo.addAll(Arrays.asList(linha.split(" ")));
            }   
             in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
```

Comment: Fiz de cabeça. Se não der certo de um retorno.

Answer (score 1):

`int var[] = new int[conteudo.size()];
for (String str : conteudo) {
    String[] split = str.split(" ");
    var[Integer.parseInt(split[0])] = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
}`

Answer (score -1):

É só fazer:

```
String qualquer = "Qualquer";
char[] qualquerArray = qualquer.toCharArray();
```

O próprio Java já fornece um método para isso.